# Finding longest matching prefix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to check if a line starts with options as ["<", "<=", ">", ">=", "=="].
I have tried:

```
line = "<=5"
my_option = ["<", "<=", ">", ">=", "=="]
for op in my_option:
    if line.startswith(op):
       print(op)
```

Doing so, I get both "<" and "<=" as output but I am interested in only output "<=".

Comment: If you are interested only in `<=` and not `<`, then simply exclude `<` from `my_options`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Re order the list, so that items that are prefixes of others are later, and break after first match:

```
line = "<=5"
my_option = ["<=", ">=", "==", ">", "<"]
for op in my_option:
    if line.startswith(op):
       print(op)
       break
```

In that manner, the line first matched against `<=` and we get out the loop.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the `longest matching prefix` using regex. Make `my_options` a `set` and search prefix in it like the following:

```
import re

my_option = {"<", "<=", ">", ">=", "=="}
line = "<=5"

prefix = re.split(r'(-?\d*\.?\d+)', line)[0]

if prefix in my_option:
    print(prefix)
```

The above code would split `line` with a regex that matches float or integer numbers with an optional minus sign. To match a negative or positive number having exponent, replace the above regex with:

```
r'([+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)'
```